# Adding an event listener to the markers using gmaps4rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, google-maps, gmaps4rails

I am developing an application that uses gmaps4rails (https://github.com/apneadiving/Google-Maps-for-Rails). I want to add an event listener to the marker so that it creates a visualization **next to the map** (as well as displaying an info window on the map). Is it possible to add an event listener for each marker using gmaps4rails?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Of course it's possible.

You should write your code in the `gmaps4rails_callback` javascript function to be sure it's executed when everything is setup.

And then loop the `markers` js variable: `Gmaps4Rails.markers`

The attributes of each marker in this array are:

- longitude
- latitude
- google_object containing the google marker

That said you can do whatever you want.

As a side note, the map is also available doing `Gmaps4Rails.map`.

In general, read the `gmaps4rails.js` file, it's well documented (I hope!).

EDIT:

The problem you explain in the comments is weird, it works perfectly for me when I use:

```
google.maps.event.addListener(Gmaps4Rails.markers[0].google_object, 'click', function(object){ alert("hello"); });
```

I guess you should try to use a more traditional `for` loop like:

```
<script type="text/javascript"> 
function gmaps4rails_callback() { 
  function say_yo(arg) { return function(){alert('yo '+ arg + '!' );};};
    for (var i = 0; i <  Gmaps4Rails.markers.length; ++i) {
      google.maps.event.addListener(Gmaps4Rails.markers[i].google_object, 'click', say_yo(i));
    }
}
</script>
```

Comment: I tried   
<script type="text/javascript">
 function gmaps4rails_callback() 
 {
  for (m in Gmaps4Rails.markers) 
  {
   google.maps.event.addListener(m, 'click', function(object){ 
         alert("hello");
   });
  }
 }
</script> But the markers never show up on the map... I tried to put this code on the head of the html script / at the beginning of the body / at the end of the body but all of these did not work either..

Comment: Read what I wrote in my answer, you could access the google marker by doing: m.google_object

Comment: I replaced m with m.google_object: now the markers displays on the map, but it seems like the listener was not added to the markers - it still only displays the info window generated from model..

Comment: Sorry for the late reply, and the solution worked for me. Thanks :)