# Trying to populate gmaps4rails with multiple json strings in one page

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3.1, gmaps4rails, rails-3.1

I hope I am asking this right, so please let me know if I'm way off.

The problem is trying to build a homepage that draws from multiple controllers, to display the nearest locations from multiple controllers, ie. food, businesses, ect.

Right now the individual listings pages have maps drawn from their respective

```
@json = Controller.all.to_gmaps4rails
```

How would I do something like :

```
@json = Controller1 Controller2 .all.to_gmaps4rails
```

I hope this isnt a noob question and I'm just having a bad day. Thanks guys!

edit 12.5.2011 @seanhill - this is one of the models, the other sections are very close to this format. First off, I wasn't even sure if my homepage requires it's own model, as it doesn't interact with the db at all, more pulling data from controllers that do the work. Thanks for the response Sean!

```
class Dining < ActiveRecord::Base
validates_uniqueness_of :name, :message => "already exists"

attr_accessible :name, :address, :cuisine, :latitude, :longitude, :about, :facebook, :twitter, :phone, :website
geocoded_by :address
after_validation :geocode, :if => :address_changed?

acts_as_gmappable :process_geocoding => false

def gmaps4rails_address
    "#{self.address}"
end

def gmaps4rails_infowindow
    "<h3>#{self.name}</h3><br /><h5>#{self.cuisine}</h5>"
end

def self.search(search)
    if search
        where('name LIKE ?', "%#{search}%")
    else
        scoped
    end
end

end
```

Comment: What do you mean by Controller1 Controller2?  You shouldn't be calling `.all` on controllers.  You should be doing that on models.  Can you give us some information on how your models are constructed?

Comment: Sean, sorry for that- I was looking to put info from different controllers, ie. shops & restaurants, into 1 map on a home-page. The answer below worked, but I am interested in moving info to the model from controller. Right now, models are near-scaffold basic, with gmappable, _address and _infowindow and search built into the model.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

```
holder = Controller1.all
holder << Controller2.all
@json = holder.flatten.map{|h| {lng: h.longitude, lat: h.latitude, class: h.class.to_s}}.to_json
```

Make sure to change `longitude` and `latitude` based on your column names and use js to manipulate the markers based upon class.

As the @Sean Hill said you shouldn't be calling `.all` on controllers but I think you have a slight misunderstanding of how things are working.  Assuming you have a `Model` called `Dining` and another called `Shop`, when you call `Dining.all` or `Shop.all` inside `class DiningsController < ApplicationController`, you are calling `.all` on either the `Dining Model` or the `Shop Model` not on the `DiningsController`.

The information you display through a controller is only limited by the methods you call in it although it is best practice ensure the main focus of the information displayed is related to the respective controller.

So what you are really trying to do is get the records from multiple models and group them together to display them in a single map.

With that said the answer should read something like this

```
holder = Dining.all # Takes all Dining records returned as an array and sets them to holder variable 
holder << Shop.all # Pushes the Shop records array into the holder with the dining records
holder.flatten!# Next we flatten the array so we only have a single array. 

# Then we use the map method to run the given code one time for each instance 
# in the holder array to extract the info we need. The results for every instance 
# in holder are returned in an array which we then convert to_json.
@json = holder.map{|h| {lng: h.longitude, lat: h.latitude, class: h.class.to_s}}.to_json
```

Comment: Dude. Boss! Worked like a charm for me. So by creating a 'holder' and attributing the nested controllers, calling that 'holder' will display everything under it? Good to know! Thanks Joey

Comment: I was thinking this works to display each location, but I will need to be differentiating between locations, ie- restaurants vs. shops. This model only allows for a mass display of all included links right?

Comment: I have the json feed that shows the lng, lat and class, but how do I call the class to display a specific marker and link to that page's info? Thanks!

Comment: You are going way beyond the scope of your original question.  The json I provided above will allow you identify which marker belongs to which class in the browser with js. With a map on the page, try `Gmaps.map.markers[0]` in a web console to see the class identified. From there you can code something similar to `http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6035984/adding-an-event-listener-to-the-markers-using-gmaps4rails` based on your needs. You should also look at the additional methods provided here `https://github.com/apneadiving/Google-Maps-for-Rails/wiki/Markers`.  I also updated my answer.

Answer (score 0):

```
@json1 = something.to_gmaps4rails
@json2 = something.to_gmaps4rails

@json = (JSON.parse(@json1) + JSON.parse(@json2)).to_json
```

Answer (score 0):

I populated the map with my initial data of festivals, and then added the rides to it with javascript with this code,

```
<% content_for :scripts do %>
  <script type="text/javascript">

    Gmaps.map.callback = function() {

      $.getJSON('/rides_gmap', function(data){
          Gmaps.map.addMarkers(data);
        });

      }
  </script>
<%end%>
```

In the rides controller I had this

```
def rides_gmap
    @rides = Ride.all
    @json = @rides.to_gmaps4rails do |ride, marker|
      marker.infowindow render_to_string(:partial => "/rides/infowindow", :locals => { :ride => ride})
      marker.picture({
                'picture' => view_context.image_path("orange-dot.png"),
                'width'   => 20,
                'height'  => 20
               })
      marker.title "#{ride.address}"
      marker.json({:ride_id => ride.id, :ride_festivaltype => ride.festival.festivaltype 
    end
    respond_with @json
  end
```

I hope this helps.